# Angular 2 with ES5 useful links for beginners

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm new to Angular 2, I just want some useful links for learning **Angular 2 with javascript(ES5)**, since I tried to find some useful stuff from google search, but there is no single place where I'll get basic information. So anybody knows about any kind of material like videos or demo samples, please post here, I really appreciate you responses :)

Here are some links, what I knows:

1. http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/09/writing-angular-2-code-in-es5.html
2. http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/how-to-do-everything-in-angular2-using-es6/
3. https://daveceddia.com/dependency-injection-angular-2-es5/

Comment: Here I got master link: :) 
**Must see**
https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-education

Comment: Here is another link :)

http://www.waynehong.com/category/javascript/

Answer (score 2):

This is a good hands on starting point, Angular 2 + ES6/7

https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter

Answer (score 1):

I tried the official docs and they're very clear
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

Basically as official suggested angular2 has good compatibility with typescript instead of ES5*6 may be thats the reasons why all the tutorials and articles were written using typescript but still if you wanna use angular2 using ES5 you can refer here :-

- https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-components-angular-2-typescript-es5/
- https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/index.html
- https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-2-hello-world-es5

also you can refer direct with your problems on stackoverflow and github issue

hope this may help you :)

Comment: @PardeepJain I downvoted on this because you should have never answered such a question. Please refrain from answering poor questions that need closing only for gaining rep. This will teach users not to post poor quality questions, and start reducing the number of bad questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ , i appreciate your effort but there are already two answers present on this question at the time of posting my answer, so i thought questioner needs exact answer so just posted some useful links. and i think my answer should not be downvoted in this case, i know its totaly depends on you whether to upvote or not, but i did't deserve this :)

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ thanks for at least looking into this question. I got you view point, this question isn't for just for gaining any rep., this question is just raised to help many new learners (like me :) ) , to find useful links at one place, I got some useful links from Pardeep Jain and others, I really appreciate for their valuable responses.